# Divide and conquer for function compositions

Tags: algorithm, divide-and-conquer, function-composition

I was searching the algorithm for finding the composition of 2 linear functions n times (where n can be as large as 10^18) in O(log n) time. I just got a  [pdf](http://andy.novocin.com/pro/polycomp_CASC2011.pdf) containing polynomial composition of 2 functions with large degrees using divide and conquer algorithm.

I was wondering whether my problem for composition of linear function n times can also be solved using divide and conquer algorithm in O(log n) complexity?

If yes, please explain the algorithm.

Thanks, in advance.

**EDIT 1:** The composition of function f(x) n times is fofof...n-times. Here the function is to be composed to itself n times. There are no 2 functions.

Comment: Hint: you're looking for a variation of the square-and-multiply algorithm.

Comment: This question will probably get more attention on math.stackexchange.

Comment: The question is too unclear...what are your functions? What do you expect when you say composition `n` times? If n=2, does it mean `fog` or `fogofog` or `fogog`, etc.

Comment: @Jan Dvorak, can you explain your approach a bit?

Comment: @bjcsbits028 `fTwice = f.f; fThrice = f.fTwice; fSixTimes = fThrice.fThrice; fTwelveTimes = fSixTimes.fSixTimes; fThirteenTimes = fTwelveTimes.f`

Comment: This, of course, assumes that evaluating `f.f` is simpler than evaluating `f` twice. If you know nothing about `f`, then evaluating `fThirteenTimes` requires thirteen calls to `f`, no matter how you obtain the definition of `fThirteenTimes`.

Comment: It is always given that f is a linear function of x. For example f(x) = x+1

Comment: Also, what will happen when I want to calculate the coefficient modulo M, i.e. f^n(x) = (a x + b) (mod M)

Comment: @Jan Dvorak, please write a pseudo code in the answer section below for the modulus case.

Comment: The composition of two linear functions is a linear function, no matter the field. Have fun.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can represent the application of a linear function f(x) = ax + b as a 2-by-2 matrix multiplied by the vector (x, 1).

```
(f(x)) = ( a b ) (x)
( 1  )   ( 0 1 ) (1)
```

Applying f n times to x is multiplying the matrix n times to (x, 1), or equivalently, multiplying the matrix raised to the power of n to (x, 1).

```
(f^n(x)) = ( a b )^n (x)
(  1   )   ( 0 1 )   (1)
```

You can compute the matrix power using exponentiation by squaring.

This works whether you're working over the real numbers, the integers, or the integers modulo some number M.